# Parse: why does my PFQuery using a PFRelation only fail after an App restart?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Just started working with an iOS App that uses the Parse SDK and a Parse backend (I never worked with Parse before!). One object has a relationship, and when the app refreshes from the backend this code runs:

````
  //Objective-C: Save Pin
  PFRelation *relation = theObject.thingsRelation;
  if (relation) {
    PFQuery *query = [relation query];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^...
      [objects pinAllInBackground:objects withName:@"ThingsPin" block:...]```
````

The above always succeeds.

Originally, I was trying to re-use the `PFRelation` to retrieve the objects from the `PFPin`. It works fine if the `PFPin` was just created. but if I restart the app, the query returns an empty array.

Then I tried just querying for objects with a type, and bingo—that works in both cases.

```
  //Swift: Read Pin
  PFRelation *relation = theObject.thingsRelation;
  let query = PFQuery(className:"Things").fromPin(withName: "ThingsPin") // Always Works
  //let query: PFQuery = relation.query().fromPin(withName: "ThingsPin") 
  // Only works when Pin just created
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^...
```

So my question is: Why doesn't the `relation.query` work after a restart?

Comment: Have you tried to also pin `theObject`? It may fix the problem.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I should be able to add it to the same Pin, right? I'll try that.

Comment: Yes. You can use the same Pin.